# R - ggvis - how do i label mutiple smoothed data groups

Tags: r, statistics, ggvis

I have a dataframe that contains time and key value pair that I want to group by key and then present a smoothed line per data group. I then want to label it by key. I can do all but get the labels based on the key. I cant see where in the doc to set this.

Data

```
            Time                newcol       newval
23/03/2016 21:26    D1_ResponseTime_MS  55.44005444
23/03/2016 21:27    D1_ResponseTime_MS  37.4510724
23/03/2016 21:28    D1_ResponseTime_MS  5.286692372
23/03/2016 21:29    D1_ResponseTime_MS  3.521776483
23/03/2016 21:26    D2_ResponseTime_MS  2.444971186
23/03/2016 21:27    D2_ResponseTime_MS  1.632372897
23/03/2016 21:28    D2_ResponseTime_MS  4.772246899
23/03/2016 21:29    D2_ResponseTime_MS  3.687779829
23/03/2016 21:26    D3_ResponseTime_MS  0.752404455
23/03/2016 21:27    D3_ResponseTime_MS  0.86613441
23/03/2016 21:28    D3_ResponseTime_MS  0.663330605
23/03/2016 21:29    D3_ResponseTime_MS  1.020344652
23/03/2016 21:26    D4_ResponseTime_MS  10.62914139
23/03/2016 21:27    D4_ResponseTime_MS  24.61302708
23/03/2016 21:28    D4_ResponseTime_MS  17.00460387
23/03/2016 21:29    D4_ResponseTime_MS  5.785255247
23/03/2016 21:26    S1_ResponseTime_MS  12.82984893
23/03/2016 21:27    S1_ResponseTime_MS  6.452076474
23/03/2016 21:28    S1_ResponseTime_MS  1.763004864
23/03/2016 21:29    S1_ResponseTime_MS  2.374506918
23/03/2016 21:26    S2_ResponseTime_MS  2.034700375
23/03/2016 21:27    S2_ResponseTime_MS  8.002695351
23/03/2016 21:28    S2_ResponseTime_MS  25.60619709
23/03/2016 21:29    S2_ResponseTime_MS  1.386355077
23/03/2016 21:26    S4_ResponseTime_MS  3.443398856
23/03/2016 21:27    S4_ResponseTime_MS  3.67701968
23/03/2016 21:28    S4_ResponseTime_MS  7.901357583
23/03/2016 21:29    S4_ResponseTime_MS  6.685758779
23/03/2016 21:26    S5_ResponseTime_MS  1.007202665
23/03/2016 21:27    S5_ResponseTime_MS  1.245214566
23/03/2016 21:28    S5_ResponseTime_MS  1.167656668
23/03/2016 21:29    S5_ResponseTime_MS  0.585119525
23/03/2016 21:26    S6_ResponseTime_MS  1.913596402
23/03/2016 21:27    S6_ResponseTime_MS  2.576953267
23/03/2016 21:28    S6_ResponseTime_MS  1.908091138
23/03/2016 21:29    S6_ResponseTime_MS  3.872218635
```

Result

[image]

Code

```
test5 %>%
 ggvis(~Time, ~newval) %>%
 group_by(newcol) %>%
 layer_smooths() %>%
 add_axis("x", properties = axis_props(
     axis = list(stroke = "black", strokeWidth = 2),
     grid = list(stroke = "black"),
     ticks = list(stroke = "black", strokeWidth = 2),
     labels = list(angle = 45, align = "left", fontSize = 10)
 ))
```

Comment: Please post your example data, we cannot do anything with screenshots.

Comment: you can get at the output of dput() here [link](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=9DC28E4A63FAF571!5465&authkey=!ACXQVt-6MoXPUL8&ithint=file%2cout)

Comment: Can't open what's there, have you tried `layer_text()` ?

Comment: opens in sublime text on a mac no problem- alternatively do an Open With with any text editor. Looking at layer_text now.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a `stroke` parameter to `layer_smooths` which will color them by your grouping and will also add a legend:

```
 df %>% ggvis(~time, ~newval) %>% 
    group_by(newcol) %>%
    layer_smooths(stroke=~newcol) %>%
    add_axis("x", properties = axis_props(
      axis = list(stroke = "black", strokeWidth = 2),
      grid = list(stroke = "black"),
      ticks = list(stroke = "black", strokeWidth = 2),
      labels = list(angle = 45, align = "left", fontSize = 10)
    ))
```

produces:

[image]

If you do want each of lines labeled, you can create a small data frame with the text labels and render that as an additional `layer_text`.

```
 label_df <- df %>% group_by(newcol) %>% sample_n(1)

 df %>% ggvis(~time, ~newval) %>% 
    group_by(newcol) %>%
    layer_smooths(stroke=~newcol) %>%
    layer_text(data=label_df,
              text:=~newcol,
               baseline:="middle", fontSize:=8) %>%
    add_axis("x", properties = axis_props(
      axis = list(stroke = "black", strokeWidth = 2),
      grid = list(stroke = "black"),
      ticks = list(stroke = "black", strokeWidth = 2),
      labels = list(angle = 45, align = "left", fontSize = 10)
    ))
```

[image]